# Unable to center align Column Widgets children

Tags: flutter

I want to align the children widgets of my Column to the center of the cross axis. 
I tried to do this using the crossAxisAlignment property of Column however its not working. How can i fix this?

```
 @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Container buttonView = Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, left: 35.0, right: 35.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

            children: <Widget>[

          DropdownButton<String>(
           ...
            ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              DropdownButton<String>(
         ...
        ],
      ));

    return Scaffold(

      body: buttonView,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

you should try **mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center**, below is snap,

```
    @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  Container buttonView = Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, left: 35.0, right: 35.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,  // <---- try this property

        children: <Widget>[

      DropdownButton<String>(
       ...
        ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          DropdownButton<String>(
     ...
    ],
  ));

return Scaffold(

  body: buttonView,
  );
}
```